# Anybody know the rough licensing pricing for "IBM Spectrum LSF" running on a small cluster computers?

Tags: job-scheduler

Anybody know the rough licensing pricing for "IBM Spectrum LSF" running on a small cluster computers?

How do they license this product?

Comment: I don't know if it's still active, but you could try Googling "reddit am I getting f--ked".  Fill in the NSFW term for that last part.  It was a forum for EXACTLY these types of questions. (EDIT: I'm at work and cannot provide the exact link - sorry - rules and all)

Answer (score 0):

The "LSF Community Edition" is free.